# Solve for closest sparse upper-triangular matrix given lower-triangular matrix and tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, sparse-matrices

I have a sparse lower triangular square matrix $L$. This is the Cholesky factor or the $R$ matrix from QR decomposition of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix $H_1$. Since $L$ is the Cholesky factor of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix $H_1$, it is sparse. I have another symmetric tridiagonal matrix $H_2$. I want to find the closest *sparse* lower triangular matrix $X$ such that: $L X^T \approx H_2$ (with the closeness being measured w.r.t Forbenius norm or in a least-squares sense). The matrix $H_2$ is not guaranteed to be positive definite and hence I cannot perform Cholesky decomposition or invert it. However $H_2$ is symmetric.

I tried using `numpy.linalg.solve` but this gives me a dense $X$ matrix. I also tried using `numpy.linalg.solve_triangular`, however, this gives me a dense lower triangular matrix.

If the question is ill-posed or if the information is inadequate, please do point it out.

I appreciate any recommendations. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot find the closest sparse $X$ since the closest one is dense: $X = H_2^\top L^{-\top}$. For this $X$ the Frobenius norm of the residual will be simply zero. To get a sparse matrix you need to impose some sort of penalty. $L_1$ penalty often results in sparse optimals, so it worth a try.

Comment: Also note that Cholesky factor of a tridiagonal matrix is not only sparse, but bidiagonal - should simplify the optimization problem a lot

Comment: @uranix You are correct. I realized this after giving it some thought.  Thank you for the recommendations.